# IBM BPM ignore case sensitivity in exclusive gateway

Tags: javascript, business-process-management, ibm-bpm

I am new to IBM BPM and wanted to know how I could implement an exclusive gateway that ignores case sensitivity when creating the decision, attached is what I have at the moment.

```
No Consent: tw.local.aimCapaignResute.customerConsent == "No"
Default Flow: Consent Granted
```

[image: Exclusive Gateway]

Comment: Images of text can be hard to read on some devices. I inserted the text shown in the image to make it more accessible, and also searchable.

Comment: Thank you Jason. relatively new here so wasn't sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write

```
tw.local.aimCampaignRequest.customerConsent == 'No' || tw.local.aimCampaignRequest.customerConsent == 'no'
```

into the left side. But I would suggest that you give the enduser a radiogroup with only the options No or Yes (where you can control the output).

Comment: Thank you. The data comes in from an external source hence that value is already determined when it comes into the BPM system. Thank you very much this helps alot.

Comment: If the answer helped you, you can accept it as valid. That helps others with the same question later. :) you are welcome

Comment: You could also user toUpperCase() function... this way you don't need to user OR on your statement, like:
tw.local.aimCampaignRequest.customerConsent.toUpperCase() == 'NO'